# How to install pandas 0.24 on a Unix server (Solaris x86) that doesn't reach the internet?

Tags: python, pandas, unix, solaris, python-wheel

I am trying to install some python packages, for example pandas, on a remote Unix server (Solaris x86) that does not reach the internet. Server runs python 2.7. I can copy files through winSCP tho. I have done a bit of research and found out I can download the .whl files on my windows machine and move it on the Unix server, then pip install it.
I found two wheel files in the pandas website, I wasn't sure which one is compatible with the machine, so I tried both, and was faced with this error [image: error]

Is there another wheel file I should've downloaded? Or is there another way or a workaround to get pandas 0.24 installed on this machine?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe copy the source code and install using `pip install -e ...`

Comment: @niko could you elaborate on how I'd go about that?

Answer (score 3):

You can [download the source code here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/archive/refs/tags/v0.24.2.zip). Once unzipped, the package can be *built* from source with the flag `-e`.

Here is an example script for Unix/Powershell

```
wget https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/archive/refs/tags/v0.24.2.zip
unzip v0.24.2.zip
python -m pip install -e pandas-0.24.2/
```

For the last command (`python -m pip install -e ...`) you would have to check the requirements for `v 0.24.2`: on my machine it doesn't work maybe due to Python 3.9, maybe due to the virtualization ([see here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/3785#issuecomment-19120618)).

You might have to install a specific version of `cython` for it to work - I'm not sure.